# Is there a usermod equivalent in terminal for OS X 10.6.1

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal, user-accounts

Can anyone tell me how to modify a user and add them to a group in terminal on SL (10.6.1)?

It seems that usermod is not used by Mac.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dscl` is the usual way to modify any stuff from Directory Services (whether local or remote) from the command line. See the [`dscl` manpage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html) for all the info (or the local one if you are not running 10.6). Google turns up many examples of how to use it (including [many from macosxhints.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amacosxhints.com+dscl+modify+user)).

Answer (score 16):

**Adding a user:**

```
dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership usershortname
```

**Removing a user:** (from the group not the system)

```
dscl . delete /Groups/admin GroupMembership usershortname
```

**Reading the membership of the admin group:**

```
dscl . read /Groups/admin GroupMembership
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an example, this is how you can modify someones homedirectory:

```
dscl . -create /Users/postgres NFSHomeDirectory /opt/local/var/db/postgresql84
```

You can see also properties for an object using the *read* command:

```
dscl . -read /Users/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, these commands are not included in OSX. Although there is a port of [adduser for Mac](http://www.osxfaq.com/downloads/adduser.tar.gz), so you can add a user and change their groups from the command line. Command info [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_adduser.htm).

Comment: I am looking more so for the modifying a user and adding them to a specific group

Comment: this tool can do both.