# Unix: usermod: command not found

Tags: unix

I'm trying to add an existing group to my user, but it says `-bash: usermod: command not found`. When I `locate usermod` nothing comes up. `man usermod` returns nothing either. I thought usermod was built in Macs? I'm using Mac OS X + Terminal.

Comment: Apparently not, but: http://superuser.com/questions/60150/is-there-a-usermod-equivalent-in-terminal-for-os-x-10-6-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't comment :( so I apologize for answering with a link but:

[How to add user to a group from Mac OS X command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line)

This should do what you're looking for, shouldn't it?